# Sort by specific order, including NULL, postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

best explained with an example:

So I have users table:

```
id   name   product
1   second    NULL
2   first     27
3   first     27
4   last      6
5   second    NULL
```

And I would like to order them in this product order: `[27,NULL, 6]`
So I will get:

```
id   name   product
2   first     27
3   first     27
1   second    NULL
5   second    NULL
4   last      6
```

(notice `user id 3` can be before `user id 2` since they both have the same product value)

Now without NULL I could do it like that:

```
SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY users.product=27, users.product=6;
```

How can I do it with NULL ?

p.s.
I would like to do that for many records so it should be efficient.

Comment: What is logic behind having NULL grater than 6 and lower than 27? What are boundaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` to produce custom sort order:

```
select id
from users
order by case 
        when product = 27
            then 1
        when product is null
            then 2
        when product = 6
            then 3
        end
```

Comment: It doesn't seem efficient for thousands of records, for each record it will do that `case`

Comment: @Roko: the `case` doesn't really add that much overhead. And "thousands" of rows is really nothing. Even for million of rows the actual sorting will be more expensive then the `case` expression

Answer (score 1):

As a note, you can follow your original approach.  You just need a `NULL`-safe comparison:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
ORDER BY (NOT users.product IS DISTINCT FROM 27)::int DESC,
         (user.product IS NULL)::int DESC,
         (NOT users.product IS DISTINCT FROM 6)::int DESC;
```

The reason your version has unexpected results is because the first comparison can return `NULL`, which is ordered separately from the "true" and "false".

Comment: Which do you think is more efficient?

Comment: @Roko . . . Both require sorting the data; the key comparisons are very unimportant by comparison.  I only provided this answer because it seems to be in the spirit of your original code.  The `case` is probably clearer.